# Why "Error 424" happnes when using opensolver?

Tags: excel, vba

I use the code

```
Sheets("Open Solver").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect   


Dim WSheet As Worksheet
Set WSheet = Sheets("Open Solver")
OpenSolver.ResetModel Sheet:=WSheet

'Objective Definition
OpenSolver.SetObjectiveFunctionCell WSheet.Cells(53, 2), Sheet:=WSheet
OpenSolver.SetObjectiveSense MaximiseObjective, Sheet:=WSheet

'Variables Definition
OpenSolver.SetDecisionVariables WSheet.Range("B58:AY67"), Sheet:=WSheet

'Constraints Definition
OpenSolver.AddConstraint WSheet.Range("B58:AY67"), RelationINT, Sheet:=WSheet
OpenSolver.AddConstraint WSheet.Range("A99:A148"), RelationLE, WSheet.Range("E99:E148"), Sheet:=WSheet
OpenSolver.RunOpenSolver Sheet:=WSheet
Sheets("Open Solver").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Then it shows: Run time error '424' Object required

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about:

```
Set WSheet = Sheets("Open Solver")
```

It should probably be at least:

```
Set WSheet = Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Open Solver")
```

Or wahtever Workbook it is in, if not the active one...